# how can i make webkit transition height and width transform from center point?

Tags: webkit

Is it possible to scale(transform) the size of the div, from center point? i tried but i can't get the result.

this is the code :

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: height, width,left,top, 1s;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    background: red;
    position:absolute;
    left:30%; top:30%;
}

div:hover {
    width: 150px;
    height:150px;
    -webkit-transition: height, width, 1s;
    background: red;
}​
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ydzc/2/)